# improper integal converges or diverges

Tags: integration

I need to determine whether the improper integral converges or not:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}\right)\frac{1}{x}dx$

any ideas how to start?

*The integral converges

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that as $x\to0$, we have

$$\left(\frac1{2x}-\frac1{e^x-e^{-x}}\right)\frac1x\to\frac1{12}$$

So we don't have a problem as $x\to0$.

As $x\to\infty$, note that we have the following bounds for $x>1$:

$$0<\left(\frac1{2x}-\frac1{e^x-e^{-x}}\right)\frac1x<\frac1{2x^2}$$

And since we know that

$$\int_1^\infty\frac1{2x^2}~\mathrm dx$$

converges, then the given integral converges absolutely.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: No problem.  :-)

Comment: By the way, why do you make sure the the integral is defined in the edge points? to know whether it is improper or not?

Comment: I mean in general why do you check the edge points? can't you just use the comparison test imeediately?

Comment: @user21312 It helps to check points where you could have potential division by zero or any other weird phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Considere the integral $$J=\int_1^{+\infty}\frac {dx}{xe^x(1-e^{-2x})} $$

the integrand is equivalent to $e^{-x}/x $ near $+\infty $.

It is clear that $\int_1^{+\infty}e^{-x}/xdx $ converges , because $$\lim_{+\infty}x^2\frac {e^{-x}}{x}=0,$$
hence $J $ is convergent.
but $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac {dx}{2x^2} $ converges .

their sum is then convergent.